# excluding line numbering from mkview/loadview

Tags: folding, line-numbers

I include `set number` in my `.vimrc` file to have line numbers automatically displayed upon opening a file. I also use the following [code block](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/17c44eda91-persistent-folds-between-vim-sessions) to automatically save and load the view when closing and opening buffers, mainly for the purpose of saving folds:

```
augroup AutoSaveFolds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter * silent loadview
augroup END
```

However, one view setting that I wish to avoid saving is line numbering. Currently, if I hide line numbering and then close a file, line numbering is unset when that file is reopened. This is true even if `set number` is placed after the `augroup` block in my `.vimrc` file.

Can I circumvent this limitation, such that line numbering will automatically be enabled any time a buffer is opened while still allowing fold settings to be persistent?

Comment: Does removing `localoptions` and/or `options` from the value of the `'viewoptions'` option help? Maybe something like `set vop-=localoptions vop-=options` or `set vop=folds,cursor,curdir`...

Comment: @user938271: Yes, thanks, I'll accept that as an answer. (I used `set vop=folds,cursor,curdir`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h :mkview`:

> The output of ":mkview" contains these items:
>   ...
>
> 3. Restore mappings, abbreviations and options local to the window if
>      'viewoptions' contains "options" or "localoptions".

The global option `'viewoptions'` controls what will be saved/restored when you execute `:mkview`, `:loadview`.
Its default value contains the item `options`.
So maybe yours contained `options` as well, and/or `localoptions`.
Here are how these items are described in `:h 'vop`:

> `options` options and mappings local to a window or buffer (not
>                 global values for local options)
>
> `localoptions`  same as "options"

This may be the reason why your `'number'` option was saved/restored.
To prevent this, you can remove the items from `'vop'`:

```
set vop-=options vop-=localoptions
```

Or reset `'vop'` entirely:

```
set vop=folds,cursor,curdir
        │     │      │
        │     │      └ save the local working directory
        │     └ save the cursor position
        └ save the folds
```